# Undetected_chromedriver cannot restart as a webdriver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

Please help me, my driver can't log in to the session
The task of the Driver class is to create a driver with settings. A Bot class to do the work of selenium. My task is to go to sleep for a while (for a kind of test) and start the session, and not create it again

My code (python):

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time
class Driver(uc.Chrome):
"The class that returns me the driver with the necessary settings"
    def __init__(self, path_to_dir):
        self.path = path_to_dir

    def _create2(self):
        _options = uc.ChromeOptions()
        _options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
        _options.headless = False
        super().__init__( user_data_dir = self.path, options = _options, user_multi_procs = True, use_subprocess = True)
        del self.path

class Bot(object):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.sl = 100

    def run(self):
        self.driver._create2() 
        # many code
        url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
        self.driver.get(url)
        self.goto_sleep()

    def goto_sleep(self):
        
        if (self.sl):
            # Here I need help
            # I found this solution, but it doesn't work with undetected_chromedriver
            url = self.driver.command_executor._url  
            session_id = self.driver.session_id
            # uc.Chrome.Remove is doesn't exist. I need to be sure with undetected_chromedriver
            # self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=url,desired_capabilities={}) # NO
            self.driver.close() 
            time.sleep(self.sl)
            self.driver.session_id = session_id # ERROR

b = Bot(Driver("my\\path_folder")
b.run()
```

I tried creating a new instance of the Driver class. But it doesn't suit me. I know that the close() function closes the browser window, but not the session. I need to restore it, please help me